# how to run file associated application from console linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, console

on windows exist command:

```
start myfile.mp3
start myfile.txt
```

on mac:

```
open myfile.mp3
open myfile.txt
```

Are there analogue command under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`xdg-open` if you have a freedesktop.org-compatible environment.

Comment: I can confirm this works on Ubuntu 22.04.1's default setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are several commands in Linux that help you open application associated files. If you know the application to open the file, then this may work . I am not sure if you are looking for this

env DISPLAY=:0.0 firefox "google.com"
 opens Firefox with google.com opened in it. You can replace the application name and file name and use this command.

Answer (score 0):

Try "gnome-open", for Gnome powered distros.

gnome-open random-file.torrent will open my torrent app.